# What does 'No carrier <device name>' mean on Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I tried to install Google Cardboard on Samsung Galaxy J7, but I found "No carrier Samsung SM-J700F". However, I see that Cardboard works in another phone (Google Nexus) with same SIM card.

What does "No carrier" mean? Why can't I install Cardboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Google cannot retrieve the carrier info on your device. Some possible causes:

1. The SIM card is not inserted, or inserted incorrectly/broken (can't use telephony feature)
2. The SIM card is inserted correctly, but Google cannot identify it (e.g. [an issue with Republic Wireless](https://community.republicwireless.com/thread/29545))
3. The device doesn't have SIM card slot (e.g. tablet)

As far as I know, the text "*No carrier*" is only an informational text to identify which device you are choosing, and it's not an error message. I have installed some apps to my older phone without carrier, without any problems.

Regarding app installation, it may/may not affect the installation. Some apps *are* restricted to certain carriers (usually carrier's apps themselves).

---

For your specific case, since [you've mentioned on other post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133162/what-does-no-carrier-device-name-mean-on-play-store#comment168763_134067) that other device with same carrier could install Cardboard, but your device didn't, it means that the carrier is not the problem.

On the other hand, based on [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j7-7185.php), Samsung Galaxy J7 doesn't have gyroscope, which is *required* for Cardboard.